# Somar e subtrair valores de vários input's depois de criados ou removidos com o appendChild e o removeChild.

Tags: javascript

Bem meu problema é o seguinte, com o appendChild do JavaScript eu crio um input com valor X com sua própria ID mas pode ser aleatória, e adiciono outro com o mesmo método com a mesma situação do outro mas com valor diferente (Levando em conta que X é um valor numérico), bem, o meu problema é que não sei como vou somar ou subtrair esses input's tendo id's aleatórias a medida que são criados ou removidos. Fico grato se puderem me ajudar. Segue a baixo o código que uso para criar:

```js
function adicionar(conteudo) {
  var node = document.createElement("input");
  dados = conteudo.split('|'); //separa a id do valor e cria um array nos dados
  node.setAttribute("id", dados[0]); //insere a id
  node.setAttribute("type", "text"); //insere o tipo
  node.setAttribute("value", dados[1]); //insere o valor
  document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(node); //escreve na div
}
```

```html
<div id="lista"></div>
<!--a esquerda a id a direia o valor-->
<button onclick="adicionar('1|5');">adicionar input 1</button>
<button onclick="adicionar('2|7');">adicionar imput 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desta forma você está inserindo campos com `id`s iguais (`1` ou `2`).

Gere `id`s únicos contando a quantidade de campos. E não use apenas um número como `id`, inclua uma string junto. No meu exemplo abaixo, estou gerando `id`s: `campo0`, `campo1`, `campo2` etc..

```js
function adicionar(conteudo) {
  var node = document.createElement("input");
  var novo_id = document.querySelectorAll("#lista input").length;
  node.setAttribute("id", "campo"+novo_id); //insere o id
  node.setAttribute("type", "text"); //insere o tipo
  node.setAttribute("value", conteudo); //insere o valor
  document.getElementById("lista").appendChild(node); //escreve na div
}
```

```html
<div id="lista"></div>
<button onclick="adicionar('5');">adicionar input 1</button>
<button onclick="adicionar('7');">adicionar imput 2</button>
```

Para somar ou subtrair você poderá pegar dois ou mais campos pelo respectivo `id`. Ou se for usar todos, você pode selecionar todos de uma vez com `document.querySelectorAll("#lista input")` e fazer um laço `for`:

```
function somarTudo(){
   var campos = document.querySelectorAll("#lista input");
   var soma = 0;
   for(var x=0; x<campos.length; x++){
       soma += parseInt(campos[x].value);
   }

   return soma;
}
```

Para pegar os valores somados, basta chamar a função `somarTudo()`.

Comment: As id's vou gerar a partir do php, da coluna de alto incremento, ali só foi apenas um exemplo, por isso eu disse que seria aleatório, e sim, vou adicionar alguma coisa que especifique antes mais a id numérica, mas teria como em outra função usar esse querySelctorAll só para pegar todos os valores e fazer uma soma do que à na lista? (Talvez de até dê pra colocar um retorno pra essa função a cada vez que seja criado ou removido)

Comment: Coloquei na resposta uma função para somar tudo.

Comment: Tem um pequeno problema, esse calculo não faz a soma com valores quebrados com ponto (ex: 2.1), somente pega o numero antes da vírgula e soma

Comment: Troque o `parseInt` por `parseFloat`.

Comment: Deu certo, e para limitar as casas de decimais após a virgula eu poderia usar o `toFixed() `?

Comment: Pode usar sim, mas tem que usar dois parseFloat, porque o toFixed converte o valor em string: `parseFloat(parseFloat(campos[x].value).toFixed(2))`

Comment: Fiz de forma diferente, estou usando assim e deu certo:  `.innerHTML = soma.toFixed(2) `

Comment: Ah sim, tb funciona desta forma.